# Get constant Variable from URL String

Tags: javascript, url, getvalue

I am trying to isolate a constant variable in the URL string of a website.  For example www.website.com/products/brand-product-description?variant=123456789 .  I need a js function that will return only '123456789'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the value from the GET parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979975/how-to-get-the-value-from-the-get-parameters)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL) object and use its `searchParams.get` function. In older browsers, you can use this URL polyfill: https://github.com/lifaon74/url-polyfill/blob/master/url-polyfill.js

```js
function getParam(url, param){
  var link = new URL(url);
  return link.searchParams.get(param);
}
console.log(getParam("http://www.website.com/products/brand-product-description?variant=123456789", "variant"));
```